# Change .NET framework version based on build configuration results vary based on visual studio version

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, msbuild

I have a library that I need to build in both .NET 2.0 and .NET 4.0 due to some deployment requirements for different versions of client machines. I created a configuration for each of my projects and then modified the vbproj file to move the target framework version into a conditional property group like below:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    (omitted build configuration independent settings)
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'NET20'">
    <DefineConstants>NET20</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'NET20'">
    <DefineConstants>NET40</DefineConstants>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If I build using the NET20 configuration in VS2015 or using msbuild from the command line my dlls compile to .NET 2.0. However, If I build using VS2013 or below my build compiles to .NET 4.0. Unfortunately, the company that I am working at requires our solutions work in VS2013, so I can't just tell people use 20

When using dotPeek to view my [VS 2013 references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y7QM.jpg) compared to [VS 2015 references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl9sp.jpg) I see some differences. The VS2013 version has Microsoft.VisualBasic 10.0.0.0 and mscorlib is both 2.0.0.0 and 4.0.0.0. The VS2015 version has Microsoft.VisualBasic 8.0.0.0 and only mscorlib 2.0.0.0.

I do not add these references anywhere within the project files, they appear to be added automatically. I saw that there is a NoStdLib element that has the intellisense documentation saying if set to true it won't automatically include references like mscorlib. When I try setting that to true however it does not appear to fix anything. I am open to any suggestions for getting this library to build in VS2013.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is better without knowing all intricacies of your environment. But sometimes it is better to have 2 proj files - one for 2.0 and another for 4.0. Downside is when you add files to one, you need to synch with another. But! it solves your reference issues. Because these 2 proj files can have references to 2 different sets of DLLs

Comment: @T.S. That was an idea that was bounced around and ultimately, if no other solution is found, what we will likely go with. We were trying to avoid this simply because we have around 30 projects in the solution and are trying to avoid adding more. Though this particular build setup would only require duplicating 5-6 projects so it wouldn't be too bad.

Comment: You missing the point. You will not add any more projects to THIS solution. You will have different solution. 30 projects - peanuts. Our structures have 250 projects. You just need to have right workflow in your dev env. Or, you can get a commercial builder, like FinalBuilder - you will be amazed what that thing can do. It can override all your references and build framework on-fly. You would literally, have to run a "build" action twice. 1 - for each reference/runtime version without even changing your projects. Final builder would do all that for you